# Validating xml node values using XPath

Tags: xpath

I have an XML structure that looks like below :

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>123</c>
    <d>
      <e>
        <f>
          <g>1</g>
        </f>
        <h>
          <i>2</i>
        </h>
        <j>
          <k>
            <l>1.2</l>
          </k>
          <m>
            <n>34</n>
            <o>String</o>
          </m>
        </j>
      </e>
    </d>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>456</c>
    <d>
      <e>
        <f>
          <g>7</g>
        </f>
        <h>
          <i>6</i>
        </h>
        <j>
          <k>
            <l>4.5</l>
          </k>
          <m>
            <n>43</n>
            <o>String 2</o>
          </m>
        </j>
      </e>
    </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

All the nodes are repetitive & I am not sure in which Order they repeat
for ex : Node c : 123 or 456 anything might come first in the order in my response

I want to compare that if C=123 then g=1 like wise if c=456 then g=7
And all the subsequent nodes that come in the node b

so far I have tried this option but it fails in asserting the value of g

Option :
/a/b/[@c=123]
/a/b/d/e/f/g/text()=1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
boolean(/a/b/c[.="123"]/following::g[1] = "1")
```

and

```
boolean(/a/b/c[.="456"]/following::g[1] = "7")
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton @Paul that really worked like magic. Could you kindly explain me the part "/following::..."

Comment: I hope the 
"/following" does not try to match the value of g anywhere in the entire response. I want to validate that /a/b/d/e/f/g=1 ONLY if /a/b/c=123  It sometimes might happen that in my response /a/b/d/e/f/g=1 when /a/b/c=456. This is just ONE value I have cited as an example but there re many such I need to assert in my response & some of them might have the same value irrespective of what /a/b/c value is

Comment: if you know the XML schema, you can indeed test exactly `boolean(/a/b[c="123"]/d/e/f/g="1")`